# multi_query not working when creating registers on tables

Tags: mysqli

The thing is that I'm trying to create multiple tables with multi_query and right after two registers in two of those tables. When I run the code the tables are created in the DB but the registers cannot be created. Te thing is that when I do everything with a simple query then the code works perfectly. I don't know what I'm missing here... here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['usercp']) && !empty($_POST['usercp'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['passlogin']) && !empty($_POST['passlogin'])) {

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);

        if (!$conn) {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Usuario de CPanel incorrecto!!');window.location.href = 'http://here-a-page.com/';</script>";
        }
        else {

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE usercp (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            usuario VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
            );";
            $sql = $sql . "CREATE TABLE numlink (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            Link VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
            );";
            $sql = $sql . "CREATE TABLE login (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            Validacion_Pass VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
            );";
            $file = fopen("UsuarioCpanel.txt", "w");
            fwrite($file, $UserCp . PHP_EOL);
            fclose($file);

            if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
                $PassLogin = $_POST['passlogin'];
                $consulta = " INSERT INTO usercp(usuario) VALUES('$UserCp');";
                $consulta = $consulta . "INSERT INTO login(Validacion_Pass) VALUES('$PassLogin');";
                if ($conn->multi_query($consulta)) {
                        header('location: index.php');
                    }
                else{
                    echo "Ocurrio un error creando los registros";
                }   
            }
            else{
                echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Debes poner el Password que utilizaras con el Login del Cloaking System');window.location.href = 'http://here-a-page.com/';</script>";
    }
}
else {

    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Debes poner tu Usuario de CPanel');window.location.href = 'http://here-a-page.com/';</script>";
}
```

I've found a solution to my problem in a question similar to mine. @furas solved this problem with a "while(){}" after every multi_query you want to do. For some reason multi_query can't be run more than once naturally. To do that you need to write this lines after every multi_query:

```
while( mysqli_more_results($link) ){
    $result = mysqli_store_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);
}
```

Comment: Where you define `$UserCp` & why are you want to create tables again & again

Comment: Why don't you just keep with simple query solution that works?

Comment: @gaurav $UserCp is on top of my code, it gets its value from a $_POST[ ] . My intention with this code is to run it just one time... It's like a installer for a script I'm working on. Anyways I've solved the problem with a while... For some reason multi_query can't be run more than once naturaly. To do that you need to put this while after every multi_query you want to do:

while( mysqli_more_results($link) ){
    $result = mysqli_store_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);
}

This was @_furas idea, He gave this solution to a problem similar to mine. It worked just excelent!!!.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The problem doing that is the fact that I'm going to create a bunch of tables... so, I don't thinks that doing all those querys separately is the right thing. Is more efficent to do it all in one simple request.

Comment: So you only *think* it's more efficient or you already experienced a terrible performance downgrade that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem in a question similar to mine. @furas solved this problem with a "while(){}" after every multi_query you want to do. For some reason multi_query can't be run more than once naturally. To do that you need to write this lines after every multi_query:

```
while( mysqli_more_results($link) ){
    $result = mysqli_store_result($link);
    mysqli_next_result($link);
}
```